# UWP - Textbox Validation Sign

Tags: c#, validation, textbox, uwp, sign

I am trying to implement a Textbox which has a validation sign at the end next to the "X" which shows up, when the input is valid. The DataTemplate implementation is no problem but I am unsure on how to implement the logic.

One way would be a TextChanged event and then try to access the ValidSign element inside the DataTemplate. But I am not very fond of this method.

Is there a way to extend the TextBox logic since there must be some code-behind for the "X" button in the first place?

Comment: Have you check this blog: [Let’s Code! Handling validation in your Windows Store app (WinRT-XAML).](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-handling-validation-in-your.html)? It may help you.

Comment: You can create a custom textbox and customize the default textbox style. Just copy the whole style and add a validation symbol beside the DeleteButton. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve that using VisualState. Here's an example: The idea is to create a custom textbox by subclassing the TextBox class, customize the default textbox style, add visual states and add a star beside the DeleteButton.

This class is a custom textbox that inherits from the TextBox class. In here, we set the visual state of the control depending on the value of the dependency property HasError. If HasError is true, we go to InvalidState, else we go to ValidState.

```
  public class ValidatingTextBox : TextBox
  {
    public ValidatingTextBox()
    {
      // Tells this control to use the ValidatingTextBox style. 
      // This will be the customized textbox style below. 
      this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ValidatingTextBox);
    }

    public bool HasError
    {
      get { return (bool)GetValue(HasErrorProperty); }
      set { SetValue(HasErrorProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is a dependency property that will indicate if there's an error. 
    /// This DP can be bound to a property of the VM.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HasError", typeof(bool), typeof(ValidatingTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(false, HasErrorUpdated));


    // This method will update the Validation visual state which will be defined later in the Style
    private static void HasErrorUpdated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      ValidatingTextBox textBox = d as ValidatingTextBox;

      if (textBox != null)
      {
        if (textBox.HasError)
          VisualStateManager.GoToState(textBox, "InvalidState", false);
        else
          VisualStateManager.GoToState(textBox, "ValidState", false);
      }
    }
  }
```

Next we need to copy the [default TextBox style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx) and customize it by adding the visual state and the start mark that will indicate that there's a validation error.

```
  <Style TargetType="local:ValidatingTextBox">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeDisabledLowBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ValidatingTextBox">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
              <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                      <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush}"
                                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                  Background="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                              <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                              <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                              <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                             To="0"
                                             Duration="0"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                          </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackMediumBrush}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                FontStyle="Normal"
                                FontSize="12"
                                Text="&#xE10A;"
                                FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                      </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
              </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightChromeAltLowBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundHoverOpacity}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextChromeBlackMediumLowBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocusedOpacity}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackHighBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
              </VisualStateGroup>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed"/>
              </VisualStateGroup>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationState">
                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidState">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationMark"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="ValidState">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationMark"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
              </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Opacity="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundRestOpacity}"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
            <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                Grid.Row="1"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                          x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                          Visibility="Collapsed"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                          Margin="0,0,0,8"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                          FontWeight="Normal"/>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                      VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                      IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                      IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                      IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      IsTabStop="False"
                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                      ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
            <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      IsTabStop="False"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                      IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
            <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                IsTabStop="False"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                MinWidth="34"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <TextBlock Text="*" FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                       Foreground="Red" Margin="5,2,5,0"
                       x:Name="ValidationMark"/>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

The code above is the whole style but here are the lines that you need to focus to.

This is the part where we added the visual states. We added a couple of visual states which is the **ValidState** and **InvalidState**. When on the *ValidState*, the visibility of the element named "**ValidationMark**" is set to **Visible**. When on *InvalidState*, it should be **Collapsed**.

```
   <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationState">
                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidState">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationMark"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="ValidState">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationMark"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
              </VisualStateGroup>
```

And this is the part where the star mark is added after the DeleteButton.

```
<Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
            IsTabStop="False"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
            MinWidth="34"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <TextBlock Text="*" FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                   Foreground="Red" Margin="5,2,5,0"
                   x:Name="ValidationMark"/>
```

Now in the xaml we just bind the HasError dependency property to a property in the viewmodel that will tell if it is valid or not.

```
  <ctrl:ValidatingTextBox Text="{Binding TextValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" HasError="{Binding IsInvalid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

For example in the view model we say it's valid when the text is "Valid" other than that it will show the star.

```
     public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase   {
        private bool _IsInvalid;
        public bool IsInvalid
        {
          get { return _IsInvalid; }
          set { SetProperty(ref _IsInvalid, value); }
        }

        private string _TextValue;
        public string TextValue
        {
          get
          {
            return _TextValue;
          }
          set
          {
            if (SetProperty(ref _TextValue, value))
            {
              Validate(_TextValue);
            }
          }
        }

        private void Validate(string text)
        {
          if (text == "Valid")
          {
            IsInvalid = false;
          }
          else
          {
            IsInvalid = true;
          }
        }   
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is "ViewModelBase" ? Can you provide the code for that?

Comment: ViewModelBase is basically a base class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Here's an example. The name of the class is different but it's technically the same. https://gist.github.com/JuanKRuiz/b686ca389077a120c60b